# Center text node

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I currently have the following TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{
     tlstartyear/.style={
         name=tlstartyear,
         above=5pt,
         inner xsep=0pt,
         anchor=base west,
     }     
}      

\tikz{
     \fill [blue] (0,0)
        ++(3em,0pt)
        node [tlstartyear] {Some text}
        node {$\bullet$};
}


\end{document}
```

which (thanks to Jake) produces:

[image: not centered]

How can I center the text with the node?

I've tried playing with `align=center`, `align=flush center`, `right` and `left`, without success...

Comment: Maybe the [tag:horizontal-alignment] tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `anchor=base west` to `anchor=base` in `\tikzset`. Or, if you want to preserve the `base west` anchor in `\tikzset` for other nodes, use `node [tlstartyear,anchor=base] {Some text}`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I can only upvote your answer in 3 hours (max votes reached for today).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you simply remove the `anchor=base west` things just work:

```
\tikzset{
     tlstartyear/.style={
         name=tlstartyear,
         above=5pt,
         inner xsep=0pt,
         %anchor=base west,
     }     
}
```

In the original solution, I had replaced `above=5pt` with `above`.  As @Gonzalo pointed out, this has nothing to do with horizontal alignment.
To me it looks better if you replace `above=5pt`, with just `above`, but that is subjective, so have reverted that back in the code above. The image shown is with using the `above` option without a length.

[image]

Comment: In the original code the anchor is set to `base west`, not simply `base` (in fact, removing `west` and using only `base` gives the desired horizontal alignment). I don't see why changing `above=5pt` to `above` has anything to do with the horizontal alignment.

Comment: @Gonzalo: You are absolutely correct. I normally just use `above` without the option length so that is what I tried and it looked better to me. Will add this as a comment.